# Tabhost tutorial broken?

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-tabhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know what this error mean for android tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963773/anyone-know-what-this-error-mean-for-android-tabs)

I have been trying to do the TabHost tutorial in the SDK but for some reason, is appears to break. On Step 4 I copy and paste the xml code, I get an error that prevents it from inflating properly. the error is:

```
 Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

This is in the graphical layout of the xml file.

```
Error during post inflation process:
TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs",
View found with id "tabs" is 'com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView'
```

The xml file Itself has this in it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running this as a testproject or something? It looks like the TabView class is being overwritten by `com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView`. I've never seen that error before.

Comment: no test project. I don't even know where com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView is. Wish I Did.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963773/anyone-know-what-this-error-mean-for-android-tabs/5017740#5017740) is answer of the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this template:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"    android:orientation="vertical"        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"            android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: After trying what was posted by raybritton I get this error:
error!
RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1

Comment: @TiagoAfonso FYI, I just filed an Android tools [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37631) on this.

Answer (score 2):

See step 5 , your Activity must extend TabActivity, not Activity

> Now open HelloTabWidget.java and make it extend TabActivity:

Answer (score 0):

You can use the updated rendering library found here: [Android Tools](http://tools.android.com/download).

Just extract the directories found in `\layoutlib\[platform version]` to `\[sdk dir]\platforms\[platform version]` and let it override the `layoutlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to android target 3.0 or 3.1 in the graphical layout itself. You can find the drop down list on the top right corner

Comment: That does not seem to have any influence on the error.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am on the latest stack (ADT 16.0.1). I tried built targets from 1.5 all the way through 4.0.2 and always get this error.