# Anyone know what this error mean for android tabs?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, host

I am trying to try out the tutorial online and wanted to put the tab to the layout xml. I have change the extends from Activity to TabActivity. In the design view of the layout xml, I have the below.

Error during post inflation process:
TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".
View found with id 'tabs' is 'com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView'
The following classes could not be found:

I have looked for solution but none of them fixed except I found one in different language. I tried using the translator on google but not so helpful.

Does anyone manage to get the tabs function.

I am using Android 2.2 Api and develop with an eclipse IDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13092

A user suggested to switch build target to 1.6 and the issue goes away. Obviously a temporary fix.

Answer (score 2):

You need a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

See the [Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for more info.

Comment: Are you seeing this problem on an actual device or just in the layout preview?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a TabWidget with id android:id/tabs as the error message tells you you need?

Comment: Yes I have in the layout xml .

Comment: I have taken a look at the generated Resource file under id class... I saw the id of tabhost, and tabcontent but not id for the tabwidget

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The workaround is detailed in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2021):

> Comment 63 by blundell...@gmail.com, May 5, 2011
>
> As stated above Quick Fix: Just change the API Target (top left of XML
>   graphical view) to 3.0 and you can see it

Answer (score 0):

Switch to android Target 3.0 or 3.1. You can find that drop down list on the top right side