# Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1 XML error in Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost

I have an XML file which contains a TabHost. I created it directly by right clicking the layout map -> new -> Android XML -> TabHost. The code seems to be ok but whenever I go to graphical layout in Eclipse, it gives me the error (see the title). I'm using Android 2.2. This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: I'm having this too in ADT20 in my layout.  Yours doesn't give me the error.  What version are you using?

Comment: I have the newest (I think 20.0.3) but I managed to solve this by cleaning the project and restarting eclipse. It worked fine after that, apparently some layout files weren't loaded correctly or something.

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was giving id to each tab's view. In the following example there was a need to give id to each textView (like android:id="@+id/tab1" ...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:tag="tab1"
            android:text="@string/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab2"
            android:text="@string/tab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab3"
            android:text="@string/tab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab4"
            android:text="@string/tab4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab5"
            android:text="@string/tab5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            />

    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:text="Hallo3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:text="Hallo2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:text="Hallo3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab4"
            android:text="Hallo3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:text="Hallo3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just filed an Android tools [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37631) on this:

> The following users and I have seen this error crop up when using the
>   Graphical Layout tab of the layout editor, even on the simplest and
>   correct layouts.
>
> "Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1"
>
> I'm seeing it in API20 when I including another xml file as a tab.  If
>   I copy and paste the contents of the include file, the error is not
>   shown.
>
> See the following other reports of this error:
>
> [Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1 XML error in Android Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12338023/403455)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4807779/403455 (See comment on raybritton's
>   proposed answer)
>
> https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/DRY4fsbwgDA/discussion